# obtener el nombre de un archivo pdf que esta en el servidor

Tags: java, android

Necesito descargar un pdf desde mi app android pero sin pisar el nombre, es decir, cuando ingreso la `"url /.../.../valortiempo"` para generar la petición al servidor, este me va a responder con un pdf con su nombre,que hace referencia a ese tiempo que le envío.

La cuestión es que en mi código me pide que ingrese un nombre para renombrar a mi archivo, y lo que necesito es el nombre original del pdf:

```
String url = "";
    try {
        byte[] todo = null;
        byte[] parte = new byte[1024];
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        URL newurl = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection con =
                          (HttpURLConnection)newurl.openConnection();
        con.connect();
        int cont =0;
        while ((cont = con.getInputStream().read(parte)) != -1) {
            bos.write(parte, 0, cont);
            bos.flush();
            publishProgress(cont);
        }
        todo = bos.toByteArray();

        File file;
        String fileName = Uri.parse(url).getLastPathSegment();
        file = File.createTempFile(fileName,null,getApplicationContext().getFilesDir());

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        BufferedOutputStream bost = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
        bost.write(todo);
        listaDeArchivos.add(file);
        bost.close();

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: A ver si comprendo. La variable `url` tiene el nombre completo del archivo y quieres solo el nombre?

Comment: se envía al servidor una url que hace referencia a un unixtime, el servidor si encuentra un pdf en ese momento, me responde con el archivo.

Comment: Y la respuesta es el archivo o el nombre del archivo? Y cual es la variable que guarda la respuesta?

Comment: la respuesta seria el archivo pero con su nombre original File file = new File(getApplicationContext().getCacheDir(), nomArchivo);

Comment: pero primero debo obtener el nombre original del archivo que el servidor me mande

Comment: @mjuan Realiza el [tour] por favor y revisa [ask] .

Answer (score 0):

En realidad estas obteniendo el nombre del archivo original de la url mediante:

```
 String fileName = Uri.parse(url).getLastPathSegment();
```

por ejemplo si tu url es :

```
String url = "http://www.example.com/some/path/to/a/file.pdf"
```

Mediante `Uri.parse(url).getLastPathSegment()` se obtiene

```
file.pdf
```

Pero el método para guardar usado para guardar el archivo es [**createTempFile()**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.File))

```
file = File.createTempFile(fileName,null,getApplicationContext().getFilesDir());
```

el cual requiere de un prefijo, un sufijo y el path destino.

> [createTempFile(String prefix, String Sufijo , File Directorio)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.File))
>
> - Prefix - La cadena de prefijo que se utilizará para generar el nombre del archivo; Debe tener al menos tres caracteres.
> - Sufijo - La cadena de sufijo que se utilizará para generar el nombre del archivo; Puede ser nulo, en cuyo caso se utilizará el sufijo
>     ".tmp"
> - Directorio - El directorio en el que se va a crear el archivo, o null si se va a usar el directorio de archivos temporales por defecto

En este caso **no es posible cambiar el nombre del "archivo temporal" a crear**, únicamente agregar un prefijo y un sufijo:

---

como ejemplo, tengo una aplicación que usa este método y puedes notar defino un prefijo ("android_tutorial") y un sufijo (".pdf"):

```
 file = File.createTempFile("android_tutorial", ".pdf", getApplicationContext().getFilesDir());
```

por lo tanto se agregan se agrega el prefijo y sufijo pero no hay manera de cambiar el nombre del archivo temporal que crea el sistema operativo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: pero con Uri.parse(url).getLastPathSegment() obtengo el nombre que yo paso con una url, el cual no es el mismo que el servidor me va a responder.                                                                                 
con respecto a file = File.createTempFile("android_tutorial", ".pdf", getApplicationContext().getFilesDir()); yo le agrego el prefijo y sufijo pero 888636707 no es el nombre del archivo pdf que el servidor me tiene que mandar

Comment: "Uri.parse(url).getLastPathSegment() obtengo el nombre que yo paso con una url, el cual no es el mismo que el servidor" , Cual es el nombre del archivo en el servidor, se supone que es el definido en la url no es así? Lo que comentas después es un ejemplo de como usar createTempFile()

Comment: claro justamente no es asi, yo en la url le mando un valor unixtime, el servidor se encarga de buscar un pdf que hace referencia a ese unixtime, y me lo manda. ejemplo: "http://www.example.com/some/path/to/a/1504011110" ---->petición  
                                                                   nombre17-08-30-1502.pdf----es el pdf

Comment: Eso debiste especificarlo en tu pregunta. Realiza el [tour] por favor y revisa [ask] .