# obtener el nombre del archivo descargado por una url, aclaro el nombre del archivo es distinto al de la url

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Necesito descargar un pdf desde mi app android pero sin pisar el nombre, es decir, cuando ingreso la url "http://www.example.com/some/path/to/a/14041111001" para generar la petición al servidor, este va a verificar si existe un pdf que haga referencia a ese tiempo, si es así me va a responder con el cuenta-numxxx.pdf.
cuenta-numxxx.pdf es el nombre que tengo que optener.

```
         try {
            String urlDescarga = urlFragment[0];
            byte[] todo = null;
            byte[] parte = new byte[1024];
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            URL newurl = new URL(urlDescarga);
            HttpURLConnection con = 
            (HttpURLConnection) newurl.openConnection();
            con.connect();
            int cont =0;
            while ((cont = con.getInputStream().read(parte)) != -1) {
                bos.write(parte, 0, cont);
                bos.flush();
                publishProgress(cont);
            }
            todo = bos.toByteArray();
            String name = "";
            File file =File.createTempFile
            (name,".pdf",getApplicationContext().getFilesDir());

            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            BufferedOutputStream bost = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
            bost.write(todo);
            listaDeArchivos.add(file);
            bost.close();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Solo te podemos ayudar si nos muestras el codigo que retorna el archivo al dispositvo o nos muestra una ejemplo de la respuesta que da el servidor. Con lo que publicas, hay muchas cosas que tomar en cuenta.

Comment: Creo que en las cabeceras de la respuesta del servidor esta el nombre del fichero si no lo recuerdo mal.

Comment: Duplicado de https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/98559/obtener-el-nombre-de-un-archivo-pdf-que-esta-en-el-servidor  También te he insistido en que realices el [tour] y revises [ask], te aseguro es importante.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que podrías hacer es incluir el attributo "`content-disposition attachment filename= nombre del archivo`" en los headers de la respuesta.

```
con.setContentType("application/pdf");


con.setRequestProperty("content-disposition", "attachment filename= nombre del archivo");
```

Answer (score 0):

Estimado,

Creo que hay un error de concepto. Los servidores entregan el contenido desde un socket como stream de bytes, y es la aplicación cliente el que decide que hacer con eso o que nombre poner al archivo donde lo almacenes.

**TOMANDO EL NOMBRE DESDE LA URL INDICADA:**

Si el nombre que deseas poner depende del sufijo de la llamada a la URL que indicas, te sugiero utilizar algo así

```
    try {
        String urlDescarga = urlFragment[0];
        byte[] todo = null;
        byte[] parte = new byte[1024];
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        URL newurl = new URL(urlDescarga);
        HttpURLConnection con = 
        (HttpURLConnection) newurl.openConnection();
        con.connect();
        int cont =0;
        while ((cont = con.getInputStream().read(parte)) != -1) {
            bos.write(parte, 0, cont);
            bos.flush();
            publishProgress(cont);
        }
        todo = bos.toByteArray();

        // Determinamos el sufijo. Suponiendo que el url es:
        // http://www.example.com/some/path/to/a/14041111001
        // El sufijo será: 
        // 14041111001
        int p=urlDescarga.lastIndexOf("/");
        String sufix=urlDescarga.substring(p+1);

        // Generamos el nombre del archivo usando el sufijo.
        // Si el sufijo es 14041111001 el nombre del archivo será
        // cuenta-num14041111001.pdf
        String name = "cuenta-num" + sufix + ".pdf";
        File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), name);
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        BufferedOutputStream bost = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
        bost.write(todo);
        listaDeArchivos.add(file);
        bost.close();

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**TOMANDO EL NOMBRE GENERADO DINÁMICAMENTE DESDE EL SERVIDOR:**

Si deseas que el servidor sea el que genera el nombre y no quieres utilizar un servicio exclusivo para eso (por ejemplo, uno que te retorne el nombre de archivo que corresponde a ese código), una forma muy simple de hacerlo es enviarlo desde el servidor dentro de los primeros, digamos, 40 bytes del stream completados con espacios, y que sea lo primero que lees del mismo en Android para luego enviar el resto del contenido. De esa forma podrás tomarlo de la siguiente manera:

```
    try {
        String urlDescarga = urlFragment[0];
        byte[] todo = null;
        byte[] parte = new byte[1024];
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        URL newurl = new URL(urlDescarga);
        HttpURLConnection con = 
        (HttpURLConnection) newurl.openConnection();
        con.connect();
        int cont =0;

        // Primero leemos el nombre del archivo dentro de los primeros 40 bytes:
        // Digamos que se envia (sin comillas) 'cuenta-num14041111001.pdf               '
        String name = ""; 
        int nameSize = 40;
        if((cont = con.getInputStream().read(parte,0,nameSize)) != -1)
            name = new String(parte).trim();

        // Luego continuas leyendo el contenido del archivo:
        while ((cont = con.getInputStream().read(parte)) != -1) {
            bos.write(parte, 0, cont);
            bos.flush();
            publishProgress(cont);
        }
        todo = bos.toByteArray();


        File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), name);
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        BufferedOutputStream bost = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
        bost.write(todo);
        listaDeArchivos.add(file);
        bost.close();

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

El manejo de errores es mejorable, pero técnicamente te puede dar una buena idea de como resolverlo.

Espero te sea útil. Saludos!